# Does Sheldon Cooper exist in the Flash universe?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-big-bang-theory

Warner Channel is promoting *Flash/Big Bang Theory* in a commercial in which Cisco and Sheldon seem to have a mutual admiration thing going on.

As you can see in the photos below, Carlos Valdez is wearing 2 of the 4 t-shirts Warner shows in the commercial. The first one shows Cisco wearing the “***Bazinga***” t-shirt side-by-side with Sheldon wearing one of his many Flash t-shirts.

[image]

In the second, Cisco has his “***This is my spot***” shirt on.

[image]

**Do Sheldon and the *Big Bang Theory* exist in the Flash universe?**

Comment: head canon: yes!

Comment: Second theory: does the CWverse exist in Big Bang Theory? Oh god, this is going to be like that Doctor Who/EastEnders mess of mutual fictionality, isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs given that CBS part-owns CW I would not be surprised if  they allowed TBBT to name-drop CW shows.

Comment: The Big Bang theory exists in earth 11

Comment: A Sheldon Cooper *or* **the** Sheldon Cooper? Also, which [The Flash](http://www.bigbangtheorywallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/wallpapers/the_big_bang_theory_cast_flash_costumes_wallpaper_-_1280x1024.jpg)?

Comment: I would have thought Sheldon's snootiness would put off Cisco myself...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most likely, yes, *Big Bang Theory*, as a fictional television show, exists in the Arrowverse.

On the show, Cisco often makes pop culture references to television shows, movies, etc. that really exist. He particularly likes to name-drop "geek" shows, and *Big Bang Theory* likes to pretend that it's a show that geeks like. His fellow Earth-1 geeks typically recognize his references, while the Earth-2 people often don't. This implies that Earth-1 has many of the same TV shows we do.

Note that Cisco has also worn a number of shirts from *Adventure Time* and at least one that I believe was a *Doctor Who* reference, so it would be entirely in character for him to wear *The Big Bang Theory* shirts as well.

---

On a side-note: I doubt that Sheldon's shirt is meant to be a reference to *Flash* in the CW, though I suppose it's possible. Sheldon wears geek shirts all the time, and The Flash is a pretty well-known DC comics character. It may actually be a reference to the older *Flash* TV show, as that would be completely in-character for Sheldon.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think a VPN will be able to get around Hulu's blocking of Earth-2...

Comment: In the New 52 continuity, all of the characters on *Big Bang Theory* are jerks and nobody likes the show.

Comment: Concerning your side note: In "The Middle-Earth paradigm" (the sixth episode of the third season of *The Big Bang Theory*), the four guys want to go to a Halloween party dressed as Flash with a costume very similar to the one in the 90s Flash TV show. Link to TBBT wikia: http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/The_Middle-Earth_Paradigm

Answer (score 0):

In the TBBT episode "The Commitment Determination", Sheldon asks
Amy whether he should watch the new Flash
television series making
Amy very angry. This may suggest that In TBBT universe Flash is a show and in Arroverse TBBT is a show